# Invalid hook call importing an external module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm writing a package called "Formcomponent", with the help of React + React Bootstrap.

This is the `index.tsx`

```js
/**
 * Renders a component for a form.
 */
import React from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

/**
 * List of props
 * @returns
 */
interface FormcomponentProps {
  name: string;
}

export const Formcomponent = ({ name }: FormcomponentProps) => {
  return (
    <Form.Group controlId={name}>
      {/* input text */}
      <Form.Label>{name}</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text" name={name} />
    </Form.Group>
  );
};
```

When I build it, I got in dist:

`index.d.ts`

```js
/**
 * Renders a component for a form.
 */
import React from "react";
/**
 * List of props
 * @returns
 */
interface FormcomponentProps {
    name: string;
}
export declare const Formcomponent: ({ name }: FormcomponentProps) => React.JSX.Element;
export {};
```

and

`index.js`

```js
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.Formcomponent = void 0;
/**
 * Renders a component for a form.
 */
var react_1 = __importDefault(require("react"));
var Form_1 = __importDefault(require("react-bootstrap/Form"));
var Formcomponent = function (_a) {
    var name = _a.name;
    return (react_1.default.createElement(Form_1.default.Group, { controlId: name },
        react_1.default.createElement(Form_1.default.Label, null, name),
        react_1.default.createElement(Form_1.default.Control, { type: "text", name: name })));
};
exports.Formcomponent = Formcomponent;
```

I import in another React project in package.json as `"@sineverba/form-component": "file:../../personali/npm-pkg-form-component",` and in the App.jsx of React project I use it as

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Formcomponent } from "@sineverba/form-component";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Formcomponent name="ciao" />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But I got in console

```bash
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: [...]
```

and

```bash
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo') at FormGroup.js:11:26
```

(FormGroup.js from react bootstrap is defined as

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import FormContext from './FormContext';
import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
const FormGroup = /*#__PURE__*/React.forwardRef(({
  controlId,
  // Need to define the default "as" during prop destructuring to be compatible with styled-components github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3595
  as: Component = 'div',
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  const context = useMemo(() => ({
    controlId
  }), [controlId]);
  return /*#__PURE__*/_jsx(FormContext.Provider, {
    value: context,
    children: /*#__PURE__*/_jsx(Component, {
      ...props,
      ref: ref
    })
  });
});
FormGroup.displayName = 'FormGroup';
export default FormGroup;
```

#### Update 1

In index.tsx (external component) I imported React as `import * as React from "react";` but got same errors.

#### Update 2

I uploaded the repository here: https://github.com/sineverba/npm-pkg-form-component

Of course it is not published (yes), to test it can be cloned on local and used with `"@sineverba/form-component": "file:../../personali/npm-pkg-form-component"`

A small news. I tried to export a simply `<p>Hello World</p>` (so a simple HTML) and it works only if I use as name `Formcomponent` and not `FormComponent` (see the capital of `C`).

By the way, changing the name to `Formcomponent` and introducing the React Bootstrap Form, got same errors.

#### Update 3

I exported from my component a simply `input` tag and it works.
Probably some weird errors with React Bootstrap library used as imported from another component.

Comment: The second error seems odd,  as that would imply -> `import { useMemo } from 'react';`  useMemo here is null.   The second one could be missmatching versions of React, that could also explain the first error too.    Are you using say React 18, but the component you are trying to use is maybe `^17.0.0.0` etc.

Comment: I checked the React versions. I installed the same: 18.2.0 for both project.

Comment: Version mismatch can be very subtle, just checking 2 projects of your own might not highlight this.   Depending on what package manager you use, there is often a lock file eg.  `package-lock.json` for `npm`,  `pnpm-lock.yaml` for `pnpm` etc,  I would check these to be sure what versions are getting installed.

Comment: I deleted the package-lock, but got same errors. I'm updating with a small new and the repository of package.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean for you just to delete it, if you `npm install` again, it will just bring back anyway.   I mean if you open it, just a search for `react` and check that all versions of React are the same.

Comment: Yes, the versions are the same

Comment: The only other thing I can think, is that your `node_modules` is corrupt, you can try deleting this and doing an npm install again.

Comment: Also deleted both node_modules folders, without luck.

Comment: I did a quick look over this and didn't see an actual answer for this yet. This is because when you do this locally your project and the local package have their own node_modules folder, the package will use the files in it's node_modules folder. This means in your project you will use "project/node_modules/react" and the package will use "package/node_modules/react" (even when it is loaded in your project). As this is two separate instances of react, they will not be able to interact with each other giving you the warning.

Comment: To fix this you have to alias all the common packages between the two in your build and force it to point to the packages in your project.

Comment: @sineverba it seems that you are importing the file that is outside of your project and this could be causing the error. Instead, you should try importing from the module itself

Comment: or Wrap the external module

Answer (score 2):

Check first that both the React project and the `Formcomponent` library are using compatible versions of React and React Bootstrap. Mismatched versions can lead to errors like `Invalid hook call`.

In your project, look into the `package.json` file to find the version of React you are using. It would be listed under the `dependencies` section, e.g.,

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    ...
}
```

Similarly, in the `Formcomponent` package, look into its `package.json` file to find the version of React it is using, e.g.,

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    ...
}
```

Compare the version numbers to see if they match. If there is a discrepancy, it could lead to issues.

Declare `React` and `React Bootstrap` as [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies) in the `Formcomponent` package to avoid duplicate installations. This tells consumers of your library which versions of React and React Bootstrap they should use, without including them in your library bundle.

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0"
}
```

You can also run the command `npm ls react` or `yarn list react` (depending on whether you are using npm or yarn).
This command will list all the installed versions of React in your project and where they are being used.

---

Note: The import statement for `Formcomponent` in your project does not match the export statement in the `Formcomponent` package. The import statement is `import { Formcomponent } from "@sineverba/form-component";` but in your project you are trying to use it as `<FormComponent name="ciao" />` which should instead be `<Formcomponent name="ciao" />` (case-sensitive).

And instead of using the file path in `package.json`, consider using [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-link?v=true) or [`yarn link`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/link) to link to your local `Formcomponent` package during development. This will allow you to test the library in a more realistic environment, similar to how it will be used when published.

---

> I exported from my component a simply `input` tag and it works.
> Probably some weird errors with React Bootstrap library used as imported from another component.

If exporting a simple HTML `input` tag works, but exporting a component from React Bootstrap does not, suggests that there might be an issue with how React Bootstrap is being used or integrated within the `Formcomponent` package.

If React Bootstrap is not already declared as a peer dependency in the `Formcomponent` package, it would be good to do so. That way, `Formcomponent` will use the React Bootstrap version installed in the consuming project, which can help avoid version conflicts and duplicate dependencies.

```json
"peerDependencies": {
    "react-bootstrap": "^version"
}
```

And make sure  the React Bootstrap components are being imported correctly in the `Formcomponent` package. Double-check the import statements and compare them with the documentation for React Bootstrap to ensure accuracy.

Look into the specific error messages and stack traces provided in the console to pinpoint where the error originates. That could provide clues as to what is going wrong when React Bootstrap components are used.

Comment: Versions are the same. I fixed the typo in the question, but in my code was right. I published the package in github, can you try it directly?

Comment: @sineverba I have edited the answer to address your last edit.

Comment: You can try directly. It is not an issue of peer dependency or other.

Answer (score -2):

In your Formcomponent.tsx, import Form and FormLabel from react-bootstrap and use them accordingly:

tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, FormControl, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface FormcomponentProps {
  name: string;
}

export const Formcomponent = ({ name }: FormcomponentProps) => {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={name}>
      <Form.Label>{name}</Form.Label>
      <FormControl type="text" name={name} />
    </FormGroup>
  );
};
```

Comment: Got the same identical errors.

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the problem once like you when I created a package before and try to use it. It is because the `react` declare in package.json, you need to put it into `peerDependencies` in `Formcomponent` instead of `dependencies` or `devDependencies` package.json. Be cause you will have another copy of react inside your app which caused the [error](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
 }
```

Comment: MOved as peerDependencies, got same errors.

Comment: If your dependencies are setup correctly it doesn't matter if there peer or not it should not duplicate.  Personally I think React is one of those packages where a semver of `>=` makes a lot of sense.  eg.  `>=16.8.0` <-hooks , unless your package does something V.18 specific, eg. uses the new mounting method etc.   You could then fix the version at the route, allowing you to switch between 16.8.0 & 18. etc.  The peerDependencies come in handy when you want say your internal lib to use a specific version for Testing etc,  but then allow the consumer to use another version. Handy for upgrading.